# How to Store Values in JUnit 5 Extensions and Inject in Parameterized Test

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, android-testing, junit5

## Overview

**Expected** - Create a JUnit 5 `Extension` class in order to manage use of a `TestCoroutineDispatcher`.

**Observed** - Unable to access the `testDispatcher` variable created within the `Extension` class.

## Extension Implementation

*Test.kt*

```
@ExtendWith(InstantExecutorExtension::class, MainCoroutineExtension::class)
class FeedLoadContentTests {
    private val contentViewModel = ContentViewModel()
    private fun FeedLoad() = feedLoadTestCases()

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("FeedLoad")
    @ExtendWith(MainCoroutineExtension::class)
    fun `Feed Load`(test: FeedLoadContentTest) = testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
        // Some testing done here.
    }
}
```

*Extension.kt*

```
class MainCoroutineExtension : BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback {
    val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    override fun beforeEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    override fun afterEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        testDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are three implementations that work in theory. However, the last solution is the best, **Store Extension Values with `getStore` and Inject Parameters using `ParameterResolver`**, because it ensures lifecycle safety.

*Thank you to [@johanneslink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32352/johanneslink), for guiding me in the right direction!*

## Programmatic Extension Registration

### Strategy

**TLDR** - Use a [*Programmatic Extension Registration*](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-programmatic-static-fields-kotlin).

This strategy works as expected with the `TestCoroutineDispatcher` created in the `MainCoroutineExtension`, and its' lifecycle managed with the test lifecycle implementations.

### Implementation

*Test.kt*

```
class FeedLoadContentTests {

    companion object {
        @JvmField
        @RegisterExtension
        val mainCoroutineExtension = MainCoroutineExtension()
    }

    private val contentViewModel = ContentViewModel()
    private fun FeedLoad() = feedLoadTestCases()

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("FeedLoad")
    @ExtendWith(MainCoroutineExtension::class)
    fun `Feed Load`(test: FeedLoadContentTest) = 
        mainCoroutineExtension.testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
        // Some testing done here.
        }
}
```

*Extension.kt*

```
class MainCoroutineExtension : BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback {
    val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    override fun beforeEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    override fun afterEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        testDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
    }
}
```

## Inject Parameters using `ParameterResolver`

### Strategy

**TLDR** - Use a [`ParameterResolver`](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-parameters#parameterresolver).

This approach implements a `ParameterResolver` in order to inject a `TestCoroutineDispatcher` required to manage the Coroutine lifecycle in local JUnit test.

### Implementation

*Test.kt*

```
@ExtendWith(LifecycleExtensions::class)
// The TestCoroutineDispatcher is injected here as a parameter.
class FeedLoadContentTests(val testDispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher) {

    private val contentViewModel = ContentViewModel()
    private fun FeedLoad() = feedLoadTestCases()

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("FeedLoad")
    fun `Feed Load`(test: FeedLoadContentTest) = testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
        // Some testing done here.
    }
}
```

*Extension.kt*

```
class LifecycleExtensions : = BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback, ParameterResolver {

    val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    override fun beforeEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        // Set Coroutine Dispatcher.
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
        ...
    }

    override fun afterEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        // Reset Coroutine Dispatcher.
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        testDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
        ...
    }

    override fun supportsParameter(parameterContext: ParameterContext?,
                                   extensionContext: ExtensionContext?) =
            parameterContext?.parameter?.type == TestCoroutineDispatcher::class.java

    override fun resolveParameter(parameterContext: ParameterContext?,
                                  extensionContext: ExtensionContext?) =
            testDispatcher

}
```

## Store Extension Values with `getStore` and Inject Parameters using `ParameterResolver`

The only refactor here that is different from **Inject Parameters using `ParameterResolver`** above, is using `getStore` to store the `TestCoroutineDispatcher`. It is important that `context?.root` is used in order to avoid creating multiple instances of the injected value per Test class.

This is instead of storing `TestCoroutineDispatcher` as a member variable, which can lead to lifecycle issues when running tests in parallel.

*Extension.kt*

```
class LifecycleExtensions : BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback, BeforeEachCallback,
        AfterEachCallback, ParameterResolver {
    ...

    override fun beforeEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        // Set Coroutine Dispatcher.
        Dispatchers.setMain(context?.root
                ?.getStore(STORE_NAMESPACE)
                ?.get(STORE_KEY, TestCoroutineDispatcher::class.java)!!)

        ...
    }

    override fun afterEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        // Reset Coroutine Dispatcher.
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        context?.root
                ?.getStore(STORE_NAMESPACE)
                ?.get(STORE_KEY, TestCoroutineDispatcher::class.java)!!.cleanupTestCoroutines()

        ...
    }

    override fun supportsParameter(parameterContext: ParameterContext?,
                                   extensionContext: ExtensionContext?) =
            parameterContext?.parameter?.type == TestCoroutineDispatcher::class.java

    override fun resolveParameter(parameterContext: ParameterContext?,
                              extensionContext: ExtensionContext?) =
        getTestCoroutineDispatcher(extensionContext).let { dipatcher ->
            if (dipatcher == null) saveAndReturnTestCoroutineDispatcher(extensionContext)
            else dipatcher
        }

    private fun getTestCoroutineDispatcher(context: ExtensionContext?) = context?.root
        ?.getStore(TEST_COROUTINE_DISPATCHER_NAMESPACE)
        ?.get(TEST_COROUTINE_DISPATCHER_KEY, TestCoroutineDispatcher::class.java)

    private fun saveAndReturnTestCoroutineDispatcher(extensionContext: ExtensionContext?) =
        TestCoroutineDispatcher().apply {
            extensionContext?.root
                    ?.getStore(TEST_COROUTINE_DISPATCHER_NAMESPACE)
                    ?.put(TEST_COROUTINE_DISPATCHER_KEY, this)
        }
```

Comment: Be aware that you're now getting a new TestCoroutingDispatcher instance for each test method. If that's what you want, perfect! If you'd rather have one instance per container class or one per test run, you'd have to creat a store at the context's parent or root context respectively.

Comment: @johanneslink I would like to minimize the # of instances. How would I create and store at the context's parent or root? Would storing the `TestDispatcher` in the `beforeAll` callback accomplish this? I believe this would result in a `null` when the `resolveParameter` retrieves the store.

Comment: You’ll have to use ˋcontext.getParent().getStore(NAMESPACE)ˋ or ˋcontext.getRoot().getStore(NAMESPACE)ˋ to access the store. I concede Jupiter‘s documentation is lacking here.

Comment: I've implemented the approach `context?.root?.getStore(STORE_NAMESPACE)...`. I'll include this implementation in my [JUnit 5 DroidConSF talk](https://www.sf.droidcon.com/speaker/Adam-Hurwitz) this month.

Comment: Oops, also realized I was re-using the same instance in `resolveParameter`. I've added a check to make sure to reuse the existing object in `store`.

Comment: Quick question @AdamHurwitz: did you use ExtensionContext.Namespace.GLOBAL in your namespace?

Comment: I did not. Here is the namespace I used. `val VIEWMODEL_NAMESPACE = ExtensionContext.Namespace.create("viewmodelExtensionNamespace")`

Answer (score 2):

Don’t use member variables to store and retrieve values in Jupiter extensions. Instead use the extension context‘s store mechanism: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.5.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ExtensionContext.Store.html

Why is it so complicated? The reason is that the lifecycle of the value you want to store and the extension object itself do not match in most cases.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @johanneslink. The local units tests are working as expected so far. I examined the [JUnit 5 documentation example](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-lifecycle-callbacks-before-after-execution) using the `getStore` pattern. It seems `getStore` is used only in the `Extension` class, but the value is not accessed from the test class. Are you aware of any samples accessing a value from the extension class in the test class?

Comment: You could inject the stored value as parameter into your test method. To achieve that an extension must implement ParameterResolver. Here’s an example: https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-parameters

Comment: The Dependency Injection pattern is interesting, but I'm not sure that it is required for this use case? The `MainCoroutineExtension` implements the lifecycle methods to ensure objects are set accordingly before and after each test. @johanneslink

Comment: I've updated my answer above in order to test the `ParameterResolver` implementation. It is not handling the cleanup up of the `TestCoroutineDispatcher` properly.

Comment: Or, perhaps it is not injecting the `TestCoroutineDispatcher` properly to begin with...

Comment: @AdamHurwitz In `resolveParameter` you always create a new instance with `TestCoroutineDispatcher()`. That's why cleanup does not work. You probably want to return member `dispatcher` instead. But actually you REALLY should use a store instead of a member variable, because Jupiter does not give any guarantees about how often an extension class will be instantiated; e.g. think of parallel test execution which is a built in feature of Jupiter and will thus lead to race conditions in your extension.

Comment: I've refactored the solution @johanneslink. See my answer titled **Store Extension Values with `getStore` and Inject Parameters using `ParameterResolver`**. Please upvote the question and answer if correct. Thanks for all of the insight!